# Reuse mapStateToProps by composing connect functions

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have situation where, for example, three components use the same state from the store, as well as state unique to them.

I would like to refactor this, so I don't duplicate the work, by doing something like this:

```
const sharedMapStateToProps = state => ({
  sharedValue1: state.sharedValue1,
  sharedValue2: state.sharedValue2,
  sharedValue3: state.sharedValue3,
});

const uniqeMapStateToProps = state => ({
  uniqueValue1: state.uniqueValue1,
  uniqueValue2: state.uniqueValue2,
});

compose(
  connect(sharedMapStateToProps),
  connect(uniqeMapStateToProps)
)(SomeComponent)
```

Are there ways to reuse and combine `mapStateToProps` / `mapDispatchToProps` / `mergeProps` functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this ?

```
compose(
  connect(state => ({ ...sharedMapStateToProps(state), ...uniqeMapStateToProps(state) })),
)(SomeComponent)
```

Comment: I tried something like:


`const mapStateToProps = state => ({`
`  ...sharedMapStateToProps(state),`
`  uniqueValue1: state.uniqueValue1,`
`  uniqueValue2: state.uniqueValue2,`
`});`
`